# Error: 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine'

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, ms-office

I am receiving the above mentioned error wile trying to maintain a connection to Excel work book in asp.net page.

I have installed:
1. 64-bit version of the 'Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable'

But the error still persists. I am using Windows 10, Office 16 (Excel file saved to older compatible version).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing MS Access database engine 2007 instead.